# Change Button Style to default Material Design Flutter

Tags: flutter, button

I style the TextButton from main.dart using ThemeData.

So whenever I use a TextButton, it takes that style.

Is there any way to not use that style for a specific button and use a different style?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: why bro? the thing is when ever I use TextButton() it uses the style from ThemeData on main.dart. Any way to skip and not using for a specific button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Wrap your widget in a theme.

```
Theme(
   data: ThemeData(
      textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
         primary: Colors.purple,
         textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
         ),
      ),
   ),
   child: // YourWidget,
),
```